# Converting "Give my best to Alex" into indirect speech

Tags: reported-speech

Suppose somebody told me: "Give my best to Alex".

How do I convey this to Alex (i.e., transform into indirect speech)? I think something like "Sue gave her best to you" would be okay, but when I search "gave her best to you" (with quotes), Google shows only 5 results, which makes me think this may be not the most natural way to express what I need.

Comment: I am also confronted with this problem, and simply ignore the original phrasing and either say "Sue wishes you well" or "Sue says 'Hi'"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with katatahito here. When Sue is asking you to give Alex their best, they are more meaning that they just want you to pass on that this Sue was thinking of Alex.

I personally, would go along the lines of:

> Sue sends her best.

Or

> Sue was asking after you.

Warning, opinion coming up:
Sue probably doesn't really mind what you say, or if you pass it on or not. She was just being polite, to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

The following might be said:

> Sue asked me to give you her best.

That's probably the closest you'd get to a literal conversion into indirect speech. Some people might express it that way, but others might find it too formal and long-winded. (It's a bit of a tongue-twister, so it's not naturally expressed.)

There are shorter versions that could be used. A common one—aside from those already mentioned in the other answer or comment—is:

> Sue sends her regards.